# verifyPasswordResetCode is not a function firebase Admin SDK

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have node.js/firebase function successfully hosted on my website at 'www.website.com/auth/**'.

The code is a custom email handler for resetting passwords/email verification etc.

At the moment I'm just trying to see if the oobCode is valid and return the email given in the code back to the user just to experiment and in my functions log I keep getting the error:

```
auth.verifyPasswordResetCode is not a function at resetPassword (/srv/index.js:51:8)
```

This is my server code that's hosted on my firebase project:

```
const express = require('express');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions')


admin.initializeApp({
 credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
 databaseURL: "https://clipify-1b5ce.firebaseio.com"
});

const auth = admin.auth();

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Website in progress...');
});

app.get('/auth/**', (request, response) => {
  // Get the action to complete.
  var mode = request.query.mode;
  // Get the one time code to authenticate.
  var actionCode = request.query.oobCode;
  // (Optional) Get the contine URL .
  var continueURL = request.query.continueURL; 
  // (Optional) Get the language code.
  var lang = request.query.lang;


  // What mode is it?
  switch (mode){
    case 'resetPassword':
        // Reset password - display UI and init backend code.
        response.send(resetPassword(actionCode, continueURL, lang));
        break;
    case 'recoverEmail':
        // Recover email - display UI and init backend code.
        //recoverEmail(auth, actionCode, lang);
        break;
    case 'verifyEmail':
        // Verify email - display UI and init backend code. 
        //verifyEmail(auth, actionCode, continueURL, lang);
        break;
    default:
        //response.send('Error')
        response.send("Internal server error - no API token.")
  }
  });

  function resetPassword(actionCode, continueURL, lang){
   auth.verifyPasswordResetCode(actionCode).then(function(email) {
   var accountEmail = email;
   return accountEmail

  }).catch(function(error){
   return error
  });
  }


  exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, in your Cloud Function you use the [Firebase Admin Node.js SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node), and not the [JavaScript SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js) which "implements the **client-side libraries used by applications** using Firebase services".

You will see in the Admin Node.js SDK Reference that `verifyPasswordResetCode()` is not a method of the Admin Node.js SDK [Auth service](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth), but of the JavaScript SDK.

The reason is that the workflow consisting in sending a "one-time code" and using this code to update the password is something that should happen **in the front-end** and not in a back-end Cloud Function.

In a nutshell, in the front-end (in your app) you verify the code received by the user and, if the code is valid, you redirect the user to a form where he/she will enter a new password, which you will use, together with the verified code to call the [`confirmPasswordReset()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html#confirm-password-reset) method.

Comment: Hi, @Renaud Tarnec I'm going to make an IOS app on this project, not a web app. So if the user forgets their email, I want them to receive an email that will go to my website which will then verify the code and then allow them to change their password. You mention that the front end should verify the code, would that mean my app or the front end on my website?

Comment: This approach is valid for the three Firebase Client SDKs (Android, iOS and JS/Web). So it means that it should be done from your iOS app. You will find in the Swift reference (or the Objective-C one) the exact same methods: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/Auth

Comment: Also, you will find more detail on the "full concept" here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler. Even if it is described for the JS SDK you can do the same with the iOS one (AFAIK, I've never tried! :-))

Comment: That's great thank you for that, so after the code is checked I redirect them my website with the node.js code executing the 'auth.confirmPasswordReset' function?

Comment: As I said, I haven't implemented that in iOS. But the idea is normally to handle the workflow **in the client-side**. The doc I refer to in my previous comment indeed mentions the possibility to "implement the handler as a Node.js application using similar logic" but it is not mandatory. I think you should be able to handle the workflow entirely in your iOS app. At least it is possible in Web/Javascript with the corresponding methods. I hope I am clear! :-) Sorry that I cannot help you further I am not at all qualified in iOS development...

Comment: "The 'verifyPasswordResetcode()' is apart of the node.js sdk reference though." -> Yes but this is the [Firebase JavaScript SDK Reference For Node.js](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node), not the Firebase Admin Node.js SDK that needs to be used in a Cloud Function.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec technically it is possible to use both the Admin SDK and Javascript SDK for Node.js hand-in-hand in the backend/cloud functions though. If for any reason someone wants to implement all the logic in the backend, they are very much empowered to do so.